# Why and how slow clients slow Websockets (RFC 5455) network?

Tags: tcp

I want to ask why a Websocket connection RFC 6455 - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455

Usually websocket connection is fast when clients are fast enough however,
when slow clients connects to it the tendency is the whole network slows down?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network.

Answer (score 1):

No. WebSocket uses TCP for transport. There should be no impact on the network because of slow nodes.

Depending on the actual working on the application above WebSocket, the server could be impacted by less-cooperative clients. If badly designed that could also lead to unnecessary chatter on the network, wasting bandwidth and even causing bottlenecks.

However, all these are application-layer or host issues which are explicitly off-topic here as well as speculation, see the [Help Center](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help).